# Ionic error while trying to import DatePicker into app.module.ts

Tags: angular, typescript, cordova, ionic-framework

I am having a problem with some providers in my app.module.ts file.  For example, I am using DatePicker and it is giving me this error:

```
Type 'DatePickerOriginal' is not assignable to type 'Provider'.
  Type 'DatePickerOriginal' is missing the following properties from type 'FactoryProvider': provide, useFactoryts(2322)
```

Here is how I am importing it:

```
import { DatePicker } from '@ionic-native/date-picker/ngx';
```

Ionic:

Ionic CLI          : 5.4.16
Ionic Framework    : ionic-angular 3.9.10
@ionic/app-scripts : 3.2.4

Cordova:

Cordova CLI       : 8.1.2 (cordova-lib@8.1.1)
Cordova Platforms : ios 4.5.5
Cordova Plugins   : cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard 2.2.0, (and 19 other plugins)

Utility:

cordova-res : not installed
native-run  : not installed

System:

NodeJS : v14.15.4 (/usr/local/bin/node)
npm    : 6.14.10
OS     : macOS Catalina

Comment: Please post the entirety of your app.module. The information you have provided is not sufficient to answer your question. Also how are you trying to run the app?

Comment: Also check your all imports where you are importing `DatePicker` without ngx in any of your file.

Comment: Also make sure you have both installed correctly: `ionic cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-datepicker` 
`npm install @ionic-native/date-picker`

Answer (score 0):

Using the solutions above, here is what worked:

To each Ionic plugin on EACH page, I added '/ngx' to the end.
For good measure, I deleted the package-lock.json file.
I then installed the date-picker using the command from above.
That seemed to work